# HP, HC, NP-hard

Tags: graph-theory

(1)I am just wondering if I have an algorithm to solve HP and are allowed to use it as a subroutine to solve HC. Then if given an input G, can I modify it and apply the HP subroutine and repeat this process in order to answer whether or not G has a HC. Also, the size of modified graph(s) that I input into the HP subroutine and number of repetitions must be bounded by a polynomial in the size of the input graph.

(2)I am just curious about if I can show HP is NP-hard, can I show that HC is also NP-hard.

Comment: What's HP and HC?

Comment: [Polynomial-time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction)

Comment: HP is Hamiltonian Path, and HC is Hamiltonian Cycle